# Show thumbnail to category items in wp_nav_menu(), how?

Tags: menus, filters, navigation

Im trying to figure out how to show category thumbnails in the menu items from `wp_nav_menu()`.

My idea is to add a thumbnail data attribute with the filter `'wp_nav_menu_objects'` in `wp_nav_menu()`. I will add this code:

```
$sorted_menu_items[$key]->thumbnail = woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail($item);
```

The problem is how to then add it to the HTML. Im first trying to find out how the menu HTML is built in  `wp_nav_menu()`. But doesn't succeed. I really cant find where they for example adds the `<li>` HTML.

**Anyone that can find it?**
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L189

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26079191).

Comment: Or have a look at [Custom Walkers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)